# What is the difference between "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" and "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML"?

Tags: input-formats

In CKEditor Filter processes (/admin/config/content/formats/manage/filtered_html) there are filters.

If you use "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" do you still also need the other one, or does this one do all that, plus limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" does not correct unclosed tags in HTML.  SO it doesn't REALLY fix "faulty HTML" at all.

You also need "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML".